# Building Relu layer : TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I am trying to build Relu layer:

```
import numpy as np

class Relu:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mask = None

    def forward (self,x):
        self.mask = (x<=0)
        out = x.copy 
        out[self.mask] = 0
        return out 

    def backward(self, dout):
        dout[self.mask]=0
        dx = dout 
        return dx

activation = Relu()
out = activation.forward(np.random.rand(3,2))
print(out)
```

error message is :

```
      5         self.mask = (x<=0)
      6         out = x.copy
----> 7         out[self.mask] = 0
      8         return out
      9     def backward(self, dout):

TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object does not support item assignment
```

I am using code in my textbook. However, I cannot execute the Relu code. Is this an environmental setting problem ?

Comment: ```out = x.copy()``` You need to add a ```()``` after a copy. Else, you are just referencing it

Comment: Right.  What you have in `out` is the numpy array `copy` function, not the RESULTS of the `copy` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add a parenthesis to `copy`. Right now, you just have the `copy` function assigned to `out`. It was just referenced, not called.
Here is the corrected code.

```
import numpy as np

class Relu:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mask = None

    def forward (self,x):
        self.mask = (x<=0)
        out = x.copy()
        out[self.mask] = 0
        return out 

    def backward(self, dout):
        dout[self.mask]=0
        dx = dout 
        return dx

activation = Relu()
out = activation.forward(np.random.rand(3,2))
print(out)
```